# Which version of tensor flow should I install?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

I want to install tensorflow in Tesla K40 GPU. The CUDA version was got using

```
cat /usr/local/cuda/version.txt
```

[image]

and CuDNN version is 7.1.4.
When I referred to [tensor flow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested%20source%20_%20configurations) I couldn't see any tensorflow version suitable for my versions.

I tried installing the lower CuDNN version 5 to 6.1. I got the following error

```
ImportError: libcublas.so.8.O: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm well aware that tensorflow is looking for CUDA 9.0. I cannot upgrade the CUDA as I am using a shared GPU-server. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you build tensorflow yourself? How did you install it? Can you use Anaconda?

Comment: @   Lukasz Tracewski I installed tensorflow using pip install tensorflow-gpu=='version'

Comment: How about two other questions?